# Showing that $f(x) \leq 0$ on an interval

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $m \in (0,1)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and consider
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{k^{m+1}} \frac{1-m}{2(m+1)} - \frac{1-m}{m}\frac{1}{k^m}x.$$

Is there any easy way to show that $f(x) \leq 0$ when $x \in (\frac{1}{k}, k)$?

I can just about do it by graphing but it is painful!!

Comment: All the answers so far excempt mine explicitly talk about these quantities called $k$ and $m$.  Forget those complications until after you've figured out when $f(x)\le0$ and when $f(x)\ge0$.  See my answer below. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just algebra really. Let's just make the expression more palatable.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k^{m+1}}\frac{1-m}{m+1} - \frac{1}{k^m}\frac{1-m}{m}x$$

Since $k > 0$ we may multiply by $k^m$ without affecting the sign.

$$\frac{1}{2k}\frac{1-m}{m+1} - \frac{1-m}{m}x$$

And $1-m > 0$ so similarly you can cancel this without affecting the sign.

$$\frac{1}{2k}\frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{1}{m}x$$

Can you show that expression is nonpositive? I would multiply out the denominator (which is positive) next.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x>\frac{1}{k}$ you have

$$f(x) < \frac{1}{k^{m+1}} \frac{1-m}{2m+2} - \frac{1-m}{m} \frac{1}{k^m} \frac{1}{k} \\
= \frac{\frac{1-m}{2m+2} - \frac{1-m}{m}}{k^{m+1}}$$

because $f$ is decreasing (it has a negative slope).

Now you just need to show that the numerator is negative. You can prove this formally by getting a common denominator in the big numerator. Intuitively it should be true because you have the same (positive) numerators in the big numerator, so the first fraction is smaller than the second because it has the larger denominator.

Answer (score 2):

You have $f(x)=ax+b$.

If $a<0$ then $f(x)\le0$ whenever $x\ge\dfrac{-b}a$.

If $a>0$ then $f(x)\le0$ whenever $x\le\dfrac{-b}a$.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify:
$$f(x) = \frac{1-m}{k^m}\left(\frac{1}{2k(m+1)} - \frac{x}{m}\right)$$
or
$$f(x) = \frac{1-m}{k^m}\frac{m - 2k(m+1)x}{2km(m+1)}.$$
The first term is always positive, and so is the denominator in the second term. So this is negative exactly when
$$2k(m+1)x > m$$
or
$$x > \frac{1}{2k}\frac{m}{m+1}.$$

Since $\frac 1 k > \frac 1 2 \frac{m}{m+1} \frac 1 k$,
this always holds in the given interval $\left(\frac 1 k, k\right)$.